# Как выравнить 1 нижнее поле?

Tags: html, css

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  background: radial-gradient(orange, yellow, rgb(103, 233, 103), aqua, blue, black);
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 1800px;
  height: 900px;
  border: solid purple 5px;
}

.c {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(153, 0, 255), red);
  height: 280px;
  width: 1600px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(9, 255, 0);
  border: solid orange 3px;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
}

button {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: radial-gradient(rgb(255, 0, 119), rgb(0, 204, 255), black);
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: solid orange 3px;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
}

.f {
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: radial-gradient(rgb(255, 255, 255), red);
  height: 400px;
  width: 1375px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(162, 0, 255);
  border: solid orange 3px;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input class="c" type="text" name="c">
  <button onclick="qwerty()"></button>
  <input class="f" type="text" name="c">
</div>
```

Comment: Исчерпывающий вопрос....

Answer (score 0):

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {

  background: radial-gradient(orange, yellow, rgb(103, 233, 103), aqua, blue, black);
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 1800px;
  height: 900px;
  border: solid purple 5px;
}

.c {position: relative;

  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(153, 0, 255), red);
  height: 280px;
  width: 1600px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(9, 255, 0);
  border: solid orange 3px;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
}

button {position: relative;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: radial-gradient(rgb(255, 0, 119), rgb(0, 204, 255), black);
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: solid orange 3px;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
}

.f {position: absolute; 
  margin: auto; margin-top:20px; margin-left:25px;
  background: radial-gradient( rgb(255, 255, 255), red);
  height: 400px;
  width: 1375px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(162, 0, 255);
  border: solid orange 3px;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
```